# What causes this get 404 no found error on Vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I use Vue to render my page then get this unknown error on the chrome console:
[image]

I didn't use get method  on xxxx/front/0
more detail:
[image]

[image]

what can I do to eliminate this error?

Answer (score 1):

I think it's something in `create_userinfo.html`.
Perhaps you have an `<img>` element and you set the `src` attribute of it to that URL.

Comment: thank you ! You are right. I set  src=0 and didn't check when the user chose not to upload pictures.

Comment: no worries, consider marking the answer as accepted